# Tokenize specific {} code blocks using Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, documentation

I'm trying to build a tool to help document a Perl codebase and came across an interesting problem I can't figure out.

The codebase has blocks such as this:

```
{
  sql_column: "column_A",
  display:    "Column A",
  parameters: "xyz"
}
```

Of course, there are plenty of other {} in the codebase.

I'd like to find every case where sql_column is within a {}, which could be nested in another {}, and extract the block above as a token. Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Comment: In Python code Blocks are created by indentation not curly brackets. Curly brackets create dictionaries and sets.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the question. I'm looking to parse a codebase that's mostly Perl, I'd like to use Python to do the parsing.

Comment: To help people help you, can you please edit your question and add an example of a nested block, an example without `sql_column` and, finally, your exact expected output given these examples?